# InternalsVisibleTo attribute and build slowness

Tags: c#, asp.net, build, msbuild, appfabric

We have a problem. We have an ASP.Net WebSite that uses one library.That library has like 40-50 InternalsVisibleTo attributes to some own libraries. Some of them are test libraries, some of them not.

The problem is that when we run MSBuild to build this project without that library it builds in ~10 minutes. But when we reference this library and just specify it in web.config build time increases to 15-20 minutes.... When we remove reference, it builds again in ~10 minutes.

Could these InternalsVisibleTo attribute decrease build time? Maybe there are some other things that can do it?

Library I'm talking about is AppFabric cache - Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Client, Microsoft.WindowsFabric.Common.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Where does the referenced DLL reside in relation to your build machine?

Comment: It's located in the same repository where sources are. So it just takes it from file system

Comment: InternalsVisibleTo seemingly has the potential to cause multiple issues and is recommended by some for use only in unit testing http://ayende.com/blog/3380/on-internalsvisibleto

Comment: unfortunately it's not our libraries, so we haven't sources and we can't remove them. But is it a source of build time problem? An article doesn't say about such problems

Comment: Hmm does slow down occur when u have either one? or only when you have both referenced? Also it would possibly be helpful to see the web.config sections that you add. Also it seems there is a distinct possibility that AppFabric could be borked requiring a reinstall, see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b6294de1-bcb9-4699-b3d9-c916aa5344db/unable-to-make-a-cache-cluster-with-two-hosts?forum=velocity